# How is it possible to travel by new citizenship passport from homeland to my second country?

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, iranian-citizens, turkish-citizens

I'm an Iranian, but I don't have an Iranian passport *(because of the mandatory military service which takes around 2 years and everyone tries to not do it)*, but my wife is from Turkey. The Turkey ministry of foreign affairs told me I can get a Turkish passport after 3 years of our marriage.

When I get my Turkish passport, how can I go to Turkey from Iran airport?

The police would check my passport, and he would ask how did you enter the country? there is no sign or passport stamp that you entered the country!

Will they charge me for an Iranian visa?

Or is it fine and they will let me go out? Or they might ask for my own passport too? *(I personally guess they will not let me go out of Iran)*

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate):  [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: The passport would be a new passport issued by one of the Turkish consulates in Iran. This would be the same as any Turkish citizen who would have lost or renewed their passport while in Iran, so the absence of a stamp is not necessarily an issue. However, Iran may have electronic records of all entries, and/or you may have needed a visa to enter Iran, which would be an issue. The fact that you possibly look more Iranian than Turkish, and speak Farsi fluently will also be a strong hint for them that you are also Iranian. I’m afraid that in a not-so-liberal country this is not very good :-(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s both opinion based and about breaking the law.

Comment: @user56513 I disagree that this question is about breaking the law. OP is not clear about what the law is in this case. A good answer can quote official sources to clarify if Iran recognizes dual citizenship, If OP can renounce his Iranian citizenship from within Iran and if he is allowed to leave Iran on another passport without renouncing citizenship.